# How do you exclude another table from a query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-entries

Let's assume you have the following two SQL Server tables:

t1:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|name | day_planed | day_canceled | discription|
|----------------------------------------------|
|alpha| 2015-11-02 | 2015-11-01   | some       |
|alpha| 2015-11-02 | 2015-10-30   | text       |
|beta | 2015-11-02 | 2015-11-01   | here       |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

t2:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|name | day_planed | day_canceled | discription|
|----------------------------------------------|
|alpha| 2015-11-02 | 2015-10-30   | text       |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

In an query of t1 I now want every entry except those of t2. I already tried something similar to

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN t2 as B ON (A.name = B.name 
                  AND A.day_planed = B.day_planed 
                  AND A.day_canceled != B.day_canceled)
```

Unfortunately I don't get it why it does not exclude the row from t2 in the query of t1.

A second question would be, if there is actual an easy way to make a query of t1 without t2 by just returning the row with the maximum description. I tried looking into it in SQL Server, but could only find the first identifier, which does not work for this "wonderful" implementation of sql...

Comment: Your sample code doesn't do what you think it does. I suggest using `NOT EXISTS`. If you return and comment I will post an answer (or someone else will). Can you explain "if there is actual an easy way to make a query of t1 without t2 by just returning the row with the maximum description" further with an example?

Comment: I have a feeling you don't quite know what LEFT JOIN does because as written the query has not chance of working. There is no potential for rows to be filtered out. A LEFT JOIN never removes rows.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried using NOT EXISTS the problem is, that i have a value pair (name, day_planed,day_canceled) and therefore it does not work.

Comment: @usr: i know that a left join basicly extends the table to the right sight by the second one. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @betlor5 kind of, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it in this "wonderful" implementation.

```
SELECT * FROM t1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM t2
```

is one. Another is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM t2
      WHERE t2.name = t1.name
      AND t2.day_planed = t1.day_planed
      AND t2.day_canceled = t1.day_canceled
  )
```

Or you could use `LEFT JOIN` and check for rows that didn't match with `WHERE t2.name IS NULL` after your ON clause. Like what you have but with = instead of !=

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
      ON t2.name = t1.name
      AND t2.day_planed = t1.day_planed
      AND t2.day_canceled = t1.day_canceled
WHERE t2.name IS NULL;
```

If you want to check every column (including `discription`), go with EXCEPT.

Comment: The solution with NULL and EXISTS does not work, because none of the entries is unique only the combination of the three attributes is. In case of NOT EXISTS it even returns an empty table.

Comment: Let me be more explicit then. Because I think you must be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing a where clause and a condition on discription. You also need to change != to =.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN t2 as B ON (A.name = B.name 
              AND A.day_planed = B.day_planed 
              AND A.day_canceled = B.day_canceled
              AND A.discription = B.discription)
WHERE B.Name IS NULL
```